# How to deal with large proportion of missing values in categorical variable

Tags: missing-data

I have a dataset of around 5,500 observations.

One of the variables is `Gender` for which at least 25% of the observations are missing.

Dropping the missing values seems a bit brute, however I have not found a good way of interpolating binary data.

Other variables of the data are `Country`, `Date of birth`, and `Revenue`. None of them with relevant correlation with `Gender`.

What is the best way to handle these `NaN`s?

I was thinking of using a logistic regression function with `Gender` as the target and the rest of the variables as the predictors, but I am not sure whether this is a good choice.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have millions of samples, droping 25% may be OK 
if you still have enough data for your training and testing.
This may be a problem to do this with 5500 observations.

Is the gender important for your problem ?
You could also drop gender feature if it is not relevant
or may introduce an unwanted or unetical gender bias.

You say Revenue is not correlated to gender, 
unfortunately it is not true in general
and it seems to be often correlated

Please give details about your problem/question you try to solve/answer?
Have you some other features ?
What is your target ?

Comment: There is no way to impute the missing values as it seems. So no alternative to dropping this variable. You could use two models, one for data with known gender, one for data with missing gender

Comment: Why not simply use the NA as one category ?

Answer (score 0):

Your options:-

1.) Drop the Gender feature as you suggested. (only do this if you are sure that the `gender` feature is not related to your output feature)

2.) Impute the feature with the most frequent value (which is nothing but the `mode` or a constant using `SimpleImputer`.

3.) Try to predict the `gender` using a binary classification model as you suggested.

4.) `Revenue` can be correlated with `gender`. Use it to impute the values.

5.) Train a model with the imputed values of `gender` and another model with `gender` feature dropped. See which gives best results.

6.) Encode all the `NaN's` into one category (maybe `unknown`). Now you have 3 classes for the `gender` feature. Train the model using this feature.

Try all the methods and see which gives you the best results